# FOR LOOP in Node js needing the result of the previous iteration

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

I need to do a loop in Node JS where I need the result of the previous iteration.

```
function jsonParser(txt_file, cb) {
var perc = 0;

lines = txt_file.split('\n');

insert_communication = 'INSERT INTO communication (account_id, contact_id, type_com_id, coin_id, com_datetime, ' +
    'destination_key, destination_st, duration, cost, description, discount)  VALUES ';

insert_internet = 'INSERT INTO internet_data (account_id, contact_id, type_com_id, coin_id, com_datetime, ' +
    'duration, cost, description, discount)  VALUES ';

for (let i = 2; i < lines.length; i++) {

    readTextFile2(lines[i], function (cb) {
        if (cb[0] == "communication")
            insert_communication += cb[1] + ',';
        if (cb[0] == "internet")
            insert_internet += cb[1] + ',';


    });        
}

cb(insert_communication);
```

}

How I am supposed to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some code of the iterations so we know what result you are talking about? Is it a calculation? An output? A series of function calls? You also tagged this question with "asynchronous" but from your question it's hard to tell which part that is actually pointed at.

Comment: You do it the exact same way as you would do it in any other programming language. What have you tried and why didn't that work

Comment: There is a Javascript manual! Have you looked in that?

Comment: edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (let i = 2; i < lines.length; i++) {

        const previous = lines[i - 1 ];
        const hasPrevious = !!previous;

        if(hasPrevious) {
             //ok you have a previously value, now you could use it

        }

        readTextFile2(lines[i], function (cb) {
              if (cb[0] == "communication")
                    insert_communication += cb[1] + ',';
              if (cb[0] == "internet")
                    insert_internet += cb[1] + ',';


        });
  }
```